# Jquery: getting response when error Http 5XX or error 4XX occurs

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

On my script I handle errors 4XX or errors 5XX via using the `statusCode` object mentioned in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). A toy example of ajax call I do is:

```
$("someform").on("submit",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var self=this; //To avoid Confusion using this
  var url=$(self).attr('action');

  $.ajax({
      'method': "POST",
      'url': url,
      'data': $(self).serialize(),
      'statusCode': {
        400: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
          console.log(data.something);
        }
       }
  })
})
```

My server-side code returns the following response:

```
{
  'something':"Hello, you did it wrong"
}
```

But the `console.log` responds

> undentified

How I can get the correct value?

Comment: and your server return status code 400? Or 200 with this error message.

Comment: Yes error 400 sometimes using http status codes to handle erros can be more conenient. I just showed the way to get the response. Also applies when you receive an error 500 as well.

Comment: You should always return status code if you are using any api. Its best practice and my recommendation.

Comment: Depoends whether you use API or a simple Ajax Call usually even on plain ajax calls I prefer to indicate my error via a status code so I can have seperate handling code

Comment: Also I would remove ' from name of propery object. You use JS object not json. Its more powerfull if you use any IDE.

Comment: Api is an End Point .. i not mean api as REST or something. If you call any ajax, remote request you should always hande error via http status because you have more control over that. If I see in logs 400 it blow into my eye :)

Comment: You can place your proposal as an answer. Stackoverflow is a knowledge sharing platform as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179496/discussion-between-dimitrios-desyllas-and-daremachine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When error 400 the response in `data.responseJSON` resulting this code:

```
$("someform").on("submit",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var self=this; //To avoid Confusion using this
  var url=$(self).attr('action');

  $.ajax({
      'method': "POST",
      'url': url,
      'data': $(self).serialize(),
      'statusCode': {
        400: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
          data=data.responseJSON;
          console.log(data.something);
        }
       }
  })
})
```

So as a rule of thumb when you handle errors 5xx or errors 4xx and expect json response just set the data with the value `data.responseJSON` and you will be ok.